# How do you echo a string from a list in cygwin shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, echo, csh

```
seven="( . 1 . 1 . 1)"
octal="zero one two three four five six seven"

for n in $octal
do
   echo $n
done
```

When this gets to seven it echos "seven". How do you get it to echo `( . 1 . 1 . 1)` which is the string for `$seven`?

Comment: What would you like it to echo for the others?

Comment: Do you want an answer for the C shell as well? The same code is unlikely to work for both it and `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seven="( . 1 . 1 . 1)"
octal="zero one two three four five six seven"

for n in $octal
do
   echo "${!n:-$n}"
done
```

Comment: That worked great! What is the difference between ${n:-$n} and $(!n:-$n} ?

Comment: The `!` is indirection; it tells bash to look at a variable with the name contained in the variable rather than at the variable itself.